# Keep rolling a fair die and recording the cumulative sum on each roll, what is the probability of the sum ever equal to $x$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A fair die is rolled repeatedly for a large number of times while the cumulative sum being recorded after each roll. What is the probability that, at some point, the sum is exactly $x$?

Computer simulation suggests the answer is 0.28 for large $x$, regardless of what the actual value is. Any intuitive way to prove this is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An intuitive approach is to note that the average value of a die roll is $3.5$.  So about one out of every $3.5$ numbers will be hit by the cumulative sum.  And that reflects your simulation value of $.28$.

Comment: "About one out of every 3.5 numbers will be hit..." -- doesn't this mean numbers that are 3.5*n are more likely to be hit than other numbers? Why would this lead to equal possibility for all large numbers? For example, 3500, 3501 and 3502

Comment: @Probably: You never get exactly equal probabilities, although it flattens out fairly quickly.  There are fluctuations both up and down, though the up fluctuations don't particularly happen at multiples of $3.5$.